# SQL Custom Order By

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I can't understand why this doesn't work:

```
select distinct a.QuestionID,a.QuestionName,b.AnswerID,b.AnswerName
    from @TempExportList a
    join tblAnswers b
    on a.QuestionID = b.QuestionID
    where a.PaperID=@PaperID
    order by (case when a.QuestionName='A' then 0
                   when a.QuestionName='B' then 1
                   else a.QuestionID
              end)
```

I get the following error -

> ORDER BY items must appear in the
>   select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
>   specified.

But this works fine:

```
select distinct a.QuestionID,a.QuestionName,b.AnswerID,b.AnswerName
    from @TempExportList a
    join tblAnswers b
    on a.QuestionID = b.QuestionID
    where a.PaperID=@PaperID
    order by a.QuestionID
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message explains the problem perfectly.

In the first example the `ORDER BY` item -- `CASE WHEN ... END` -- doesn't appear in the `SELECT` list.

In the second example the `ORDER BY` item -- `a.QuestionID` -- does appear in the `SELECT` list.

To fix the first example you'll need to do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.QuestionID, a.QuestionName, b.AnswerID, b.AnswerName,
                CASE WHEN a.QuestionName = 'A' THEN 0
                     WHEN a.QuestionName = 'B' THEN 1
                     ELSE a.QuestionID
                END
FROM @TempExportList AS a
    JOIN tblAnswers AS b
        ON a.QuestionID = b.QuestionID
WHERE a.PaperID = @PaperID
ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.QuestionName = 'A' THEN 0
              WHEN a.QuestionName = 'B' THEN 1
              ELSE a.QuestionID
         END
```

Comment: Thanks. I would have thought it was refering to a.QuestionName and a.QuestionID not being in the select, with 0,1...n just being an order number and not needed as part of the select.

Comment: Thank you. Error is clear but i thought only columns must be added. For me, SQL can be pretty simple and very confusing at the same time -_-

Answer (score 4):

You can get around this with a CTE

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT a.QuestionID,a.QuestionName,b.AnswerID,b.AnswerName
    FROM @TempExportList a
    JOIN tblAnswers b
    ON a.QuestionID = b.QuestionID
    WHERE a.PaperID=@PaperID
)
SELECT   *
FROM     T
ORDER BY
         CASE
                  WHEN QuestionName='A'
                  THEN 0
                  WHEN QuestionName='B'
                  THEN 1
                  ELSE QuestionID
         END
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought the message self explanitory.

You have selected a distinct on a.QuestionID,a.QuestionName,b.AnswerID and b.AnswerName. Therefore, there could be rows of data with the same respective values for each of these fields, but a different one for your `case` statement.

Consider this

```
a.QuestionID  a.QuestionName  b.AnswerID   b.AnswerName  [case statement]

1             'One'           2            'Two'         0
1             'One'           2            'Two'         1
```

How does the query know which value in the last column to use in the order? Is it 0? It is 1? Quite simply, it can't determine, so it can't use it, hence the error.

The second example is fine, because a.QuestionID does appear in the SELECT list, and the query can happily apply the ordering.

Comment: This is a bit of a bogus argument IMO. It **could** determine that only deterministic functions were being used though and that the case expression in the order by only used columns in the select list. SQL Server 2000 allows you to do this. AFAIK this was a breaking change in SQL Server 2005 in order to meet the ANSI standard.