# Specific Ordering in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. In this database, I have a result set that looks like the following:

```
ID  Name          Department    LastOrderDate
--  ----          ----------    -------------
1   Golf Balls    Sports        01/01/2015
2   Compact Disc  Electronics   02/01/2015
3   Tires         Automotive    01/15/2015
4   T-Shirt       Clothing      01/10/2015
5   DVD           Electronics   01/07/2015
6   Tennis Balls  Sports        01/09/2015   
7   Sweatshirt    Clothing      01/04/2015
...
```

For some reason, my users want to get the results ordered by department, then last order date. However, not by department name. Instead, the departments will be in a specific order. For example, they want to see the results ordered by Electronics, Automotive, Sports, then Clothing. To throw another kink in works, I cannot update the table schema.

Is there a way to do this with a SQL Query? If so, how? Currently, I'm stuck at

```
SELECT *
FROM
  vOrders o
ORDER BY
  o.LastOrderDate
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335374/sql-custom-order-by

Comment: If there is a [depts] table and you can add a *new* table create one with [deptId | sortOrder] and join

Comment: You can't update the table to add a new column *and* you can't create a new table? Is this like a riddle or something? :)

Comment: This is presentation logic that should be handled by whatever front-end application is processing the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` expression ;

```
order by case when department = 'Electronics' then 1
              when department = 'Automotive' then 2
              when department = 'Sports' then 3
              when department = 'Clothing' then 4
              else 5 end
```

Comment: May want to have a case else as 5 so everything else comes after those otherwise wouldn't nulls come first?

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work when they have more departments.

Comment: @khanhTo true, but the requirements are very specific about ordering.  Unless Xam goes back and asks "What should happen when you have more departments.." this is as close as it's likely to get.  aside from needing `, lastorderdate`  on the order by and a else for the case...(or a `nulls last` statement)  this is about as good as you'll get without adding a sort sequence to the database when users want to "Specify" the sort order.

Answer (score 1):

create a table for the departments that has the name (or better id) of the department and the display order. then join to that table and order by the display order column.

alternatively you can do a order by case:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Department = 'Electronics' THEN 1
     WHEN Department = 'Automotive' THEN 2
...
END
```

(that is not recommended for larger tables)

Answer (score 0):

Here solution with CTE

```
with c (iOrder, dept) 
as (
Select 1, 'Electronics'
Union
Select 2, 'Automotive'
Union
Select 3, 'Sports'
Union
Select 4, 'Clothing'
)
Select * from c
SELECT o.*
FROM
  vOrders o join c
  on c.dept = o.Department    
ORDER BY
  c.iOrder
```